# How to merge several arrays into one array and sort files of all arrays by date?

Tags: php

I have a function that looks for files in subfolders and lists them in the order of the folders. How can I merge all the files into one array and sort them by the date the file was created?

Many subfolders are located in "post"-folder. Many files are located in subfolders.

```
/posts
   /subfolder 1
      file 1 (created 01/01/19)
      file 3 (created 03/03/19)
   /subfolder 2
      file 2 (created 02/02/19)
      file 4 (created 04/04/19)
   ...
```

GetPostList-function created an array of files in one subfolder and output them (set variables from files).

```
function GetPostList($dir) {
    $postlist = '';
    $postmarkup = '';
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/posts/' . $dir;
    $pages = array();
    $handle = opendir($path);
    if ($handle != false)
    {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false)
        {
            if (is_file($path . $file))
            {
                $i = filemtime($path . $file) . ',' . $file;
                $pages[$i] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    krsort($pages);
    foreach ($pages as $i => $page)
    {
        $title = GetContent($page, 'title', $dir);
        $date = GetContent($page, 'date', $dir);
        $caterory = GetContent($page, 'category', $dir);
        $fileaddon = strpos($page, ".");
        $filename = substr($page, 0, $fileaddon);
        $posturl = $dir.$filename;
        $postmarkup .= '
            <p>
                <a href="'.$posturl.'" title="'.$title.'">
                    '.$title.'<br>
                    <span>'.$caterory.'</span> | <span>'.$date.'</span>
                </a>
            </p>
        ';
    }
    if (empty($pages))
    $postlist .= '<p>Empty!</p>';
    $postlist .= $postmarkup;
    return $postlist;
}
```

GetAllPost-function created an arrays of files in all subfolders, but output apart (from first subfolder, then from second subfolder...):

```
function GetAllPost()
{
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/posts/';
    $readdirectory = dir($path);
    while(false !== ($dir = $readdirectory->read()))
    {
        if($dir != "." && $dir != "..")
        {
            $subpages = GetPostList($dir.'/');
            echo $subpages;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
file 1 (created 01/01/19)
file 3 (created 03/03/19)
file 2 (created 02/02/19)
file 4 (created 04/04/19)
...
```

How to merge and sort them by date of creation?

```
file 1 (created 01/01/19)
file 2 (created 02/02/19)
file 3 (created 03/03/19)
file 4 (created 04/04/19)
...
```

Comment: Separate the code that lists all the files from the code that formats it. The code that lists all the files can return a 2-dimensional array, which you can sort by date. Then you can format it.

Comment: Barmar, thank You. Of course, this is more correct in terms of OOP.